# a barn vs the barn

Tags: articles

What is the difference between these two sentences:

> Tom was hiding in **the** barn.
>
> Tom was hiding in **a** barn.

Comment: A question perhaps better suited for https://ell.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1):

Here are two examples:

> Tom had been shot down over occupied France and was trying to get back to England. One night he was hiding in **a** barn.
>
> When the police came to his father's farm Tom was hiding in **the** barn.

The difference is this:

In the first case the context does not identify the specific barn, it's just one that Tom found on his travels. As the barn is not identified we use the indefinite article **a**.

In the second case the barn is identified as being the one on Tom's father's farm. Since it is identified we use the definite article **the**.

If there was more than one barn on Tom's father's farm we would either have to use the indefinite article and say "When the police came to his father's farm Tom was hiding in **a** barn" or identify the specific barn by saying "When the police came to his father's farm Tom was hiding in **the big** barn".

Comment: Minus one? What's wrong with that?

Comment: +1 to offset the drive-by downvote. Most likely it was simply because the question was marked as a duplicate. (Some people will downvote any answer to such questions.)

Comment: @BoldBen You should have answered at the duplicate rather than here.